# Nodejs error "Callback was already called error."

Tags: javascript, node.js

For some reason, this part of the code is causing a callback is already called issue, if it does not enter the "if" loop, it returns accurately. Unable to figure out why it partially works.
Why are the return statements acting differently?

```
   **if (!args.is_table) {
      return cbk(null, {peers: forwards.peers});
    }**
```

Here's the error:

```
***if (fn === null) throw new Error("Callback was already called.");
                         ^
Error: Callback was already called.***



module.exports = (args, cbk) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return asyncAuto({

      // Final forwards table
      allForwards: ['forwards', ({forwards}, cbk) => {
        if (!args.is_table) {
          return cbk(null, {peers: forwards.peers});
        }

        const isWideSize = !size || size.get().width > wideSizeCols;

        return cbk(null, {
          peers: forwards.peers,
          rows: []
            .concat([notNull([
              'Alias',
              'Earned In',
              'Earned Out',
              'Inbound',
              'Outbound',
              !!isWideSize ? 'Public Key' : null,
            ]).map(n => !args.is_monochrome ? bold(n) : n)])
            .concat(forwards.peers.map(peer => {
              return notNull([
                chartAliasForPeer({
                  alias: peer.alias,
                  icons: peer.icons,
                  is_disconnected: peer.is_disconnected,
                  is_forwarding: peer.is_forwarding,
                  is_inactive: peer.is_inactive,
                  is_pending: peer.is_pending,
                  is_private: peer.is_private,
                  public_key: peer.public_key,
                }).display,
                formatTokens({
                  is_monochrome: args.is_monochrome,
                  tokens: peer.liquidity_outbound,
                }).display,
                !!isWideSize ? peer.public_key : null,
              ]);
            })),
        });
      }],
    },
    returnResult({reject, resolve, of: 'allForwards'}, cbk));
  });
};
```

Comment: Why are you mixing callbacks and promises?  That's a clear anti-pattern and often makes accurate control flow and error handling very difficult.

Comment: What is the point of this code?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I was basically contributing to a repo and found an issue. If you need the whole context:
This is the index page which from where the call happens:
https://github.com/alexbosworth/balanceofsatoshis/blob/master/bos#L610

And this is the file that is called which I trimmed and copy pasted.

https://github.com/alexbosworth/balanceofsatoshis/blob/master/network/get_forwards.js